# Wait async for a event from a never ending Task

Tags: c#, events, .net-core, channel, system.threading.channels

Currently I'am build a webserver that needs to wait from incoming messages, but i need to wait asynchronisally for these messages. These messages are received in an other Task that keeps running. The endless task pushes Events and the other Task needs to wait for one of these events too be received.

*If will make a sketch if needed to visualize the problem better*

I have seen the TaskCompletionSource class but the task will not complete except when the client disconnects so that's not going to work. Await for the task is exactly the same.

Is there a Library or build in solution for C#/.net core?

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to create this behaviour using `Task` and `TaskCompletionSource` if that is what you really want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29355817/10608418

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your needs. What did you mean by _other Task needs to wait for one of these events_? Waiting for an event asynchronously sounds like a normal event. That event is called in the scope of the _never ending Task_. Do you mean something like this: [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mngX9m)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the new `Channel<T>` API in .NET Core 2.1 and [System.Threading.Channels](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Channels/4.5.0) that lets you consume a queue asynchronously:

```
Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();
...
ChannelReader<int> c = channel.Reader;
while (await c.WaitToReadAsync())
{
    if (await c.ReadAsync(out int item))
    {
         // process item...
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://ndportmann.com/system-threading-channels/) blog post for an introduction and more examples of how to use it.

Comment: Channels are used in SignalR already to implement [event streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The pattern shown there is significant - create the channel *inside* the producer method and only expose the ChannelReader. This way there's no confusion about who can write to the channel or who is responsible for closing it

Answer (score 3):

**Channels**

ASP.NET Core SignalR uses [Channels to implement event streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.2) - a publisher method produces events asynchronously that are processed by another method. In SignalR's case it's a consumer that pushes each new event to the clients.

Doing the same in your code is easy, but make sure to follow the pattern shown in the SignalR docs - the channel is created by the worker itself and never exposed to the callers. This means there's no ambiguity about the state of the channels as only the worker can close it.

Another important point is that you *have* to close the channel when finished, even if there's an exception. Otherwise, the consumers will block indefinitely.

You'll also need to pass a CancellationToken to the producer so you can terminate it at some point. Even if you don't intend to explicitly cancel the producer, you need a way to tell it to stop when the application terminates.

The following method creates the channel *and* ensures it closes even when an exception occurs.

```
ChannelReader<int> MyProducer(someparameters,CancellationToken token)
{
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;

    _ = Task.Run(async()=>{
            while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var i= ... //do something to produce a value
                await writer.WriteAsync(i,token);
            }
        },token)
        //IMPORTANT: Close the channel no matter what.
        .ContinueWith(t=>writer.Complete(t.Exception));                
    return channel.Reader;
}
```

`t.Exception` will be null if the producer finishes gracefully or if the worker task is cancelled through the token. There's no reason to use `ChannelReader.TryComplete` as only one task is writing to the writer at a time.

A consumer only needs that reader to consume the events:

```
async Task MyConsumer(ChannerReader<int> reader,CancellationToken token)
{
    while (await reader.WaitToReadAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        while (reader.TryRead(out int item))
        {
           //Use that integer
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used with :

```
var reader=MyProducer(...,cts.Token);
await MyConsumer(reader,cts.Token);
```

**IAsyncEnumerable**

I cheated a bit here because I copied the loop code from the [ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs) method which returns an IAsyncEnumerable which allows looping asynchronously. In .NET Core 3.0 and .NET Standard 2.1 (but not only that) one could replace the consumer with just :

```
await foreach (var i from reader.ReadAllAsync(token))
{
     //Use that integer
}
```

The [Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/) package adds the same interfaces to previous .NET versions